# Show related li according to selected li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, show-hide

I have a list:

```
<ul class="products">
  <li class="products p1">first</li>
  <li class="description p1">first</li>
  <li class="products p2">second</li>
  <li class="description p2">second</li>
  <li class="products p3">third</li>
  <li class="description p3">third</li>
  <li class="products p4">fourth</li>
  <li class="description p4">fourth</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to use jquery to:
1-hide other li s when user clicks on one except the clicked one.
2-show all li s when user clicks again on the active li.
I used the script below:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".products li").click(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          $(".products li").show("slow");
          $(this).removeClass("active");
     } else {
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
     }
});
});
```

It works fine.
now I want to show the related description li for the active li.
for example if the active li is the li with class:p2, then the below description li needs to be shown and othe li s go hidden:

```
  <li class="description p2">second</li>
```

Description li s are hidden at the beginning.
I dont know how to select the correct li according to class name. There should be a jQuery trick to select li s by class name with mask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.active` class to next `li` (`$(this).next().addClass("active");`), and also change selector to `li.products` because all `li` are clickable:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".products li.products").click(function(){
         if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
              $(".products li").show("slow");
              $(this).removeClass("active");
              $(this).next().removeClass("active");
         } else {
              $(this).addClass("active");
              $(this).next().addClass("active");
              $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
         }
    });
}); ​​
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XKCx7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.next()` jQuery function. Since the description is always the next `li` element from the active one, you should be able to get the next sibling and use `.show()`.

```
.next():

Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a   
selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.
```

http://api.jquery.com/next/